# What is the best way to raise a succulent using still aquaponics?

Tags: growing-medium

I am really new to gardening and have fallen in love with the idea of raising plants in a very low maintenance setting because I travel a lot. I have a lot of lucky bamboo and just got a pothos plant. I like them because they can just stay in water with a little bit of fertilizer every now and then. I saw somewhere I can do that with succulents like jade, I was just wondering how that can be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Succulents are adapted to survive in dry climates and thus they are not suited to aquaponic growing.

**It might be possible.** I know that you can root *some* succulents in water. This can be used when propagating cuttings. However, I do not know how long they survive in water or if it is feasible to keep them in water permanently.

**I have never seen a jade plant successfully grown or propagated in water.** That does not mean it is impossible but it is improbable. Jade plants grow easily in soil so there's not really a reason to go through all the trouble of trying to grow them in water.

Most succulents are more low maintenance than any plants you are going to grow in an aquaponic environment (unless you have a fully automated aquaponic system that accounts for evaporation). There are some types of cacti that you can get away with watering only once every one to two months. Succulents are also extremely tough and can come back from serious neglect (not getting enough water).

If you are simply looking for a low maintenance plant than a succulent grown in soil is likely the best option. However, **if you insist that it is grown hydroponically there is no reason not to try it**. Be sure to never let the base of the succulent touch the water, only let the roots themselves dangle into the water. You are likely to have a better chance of success with a rain forest cactus (Orchid cactus or Christmas cactus) as these are adapted to moister environments.

In case you need something that can survive 3+ months of neglect then you can look into closed terrariums. It is possible to set them up so that they basically don't need to be watered at all.